# Number of integer solutions of two similar equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find the number of integer solutions of:
>
> (a) $${1\over\sqrt{x}}+{1\over\sqrt{y}} = {1\over\sqrt{20}}$$
>
> (b) $${1\over\sqrt{x}}+{1\over\sqrt{y}} = {1\over\sqrt{2014}}$$

I know the solution for (a), but not for (b).

Comment: What did you do for getting the solutions of $(a)$ ?

Comment: @Claude First, show both x and y must be divisible by 5, than sqrt(x) and sqrt(x) are rational numbers... and reduce to simpler diophantine equation.

Comment: I would like some fresh ideas, so I am not attaching solution for (a). However, if someone insists, I will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, consider 
$$ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{y}} = \dfrac{1}{a \sqrt{b}}$$
where $a$, $b$ are positive integers and $b > 1$ is squarefree, and we want $x$, $y$ to be positive integers.  We can 
rearrange this as
$$ \sqrt{x} = \dfrac{a \sqrt{by}}{\sqrt{y} - a \sqrt{b}}$$
so we must have $\sqrt{y} > a \sqrt{b}$ as well as
$$ x = \dfrac{a^2by^2}{y + a^2 b - 2 a \sqrt{by}} = \dfrac{a^2 b y^2 (y + a^2 b + 2 a \sqrt{by})}{(y + a^2 b)^2 - 4 a^2by }$$
Now in order for the right side to be rational, $\sqrt{by}$ must be an integer.
Thus $y = b z^2$ for some positive integer $z$.
Note that the condition $\sqrt{y} > a \sqrt{b}$ says $z > a$.  Thus let $z = a + t$ where $t$ is a positive integer.  Substituting $y = b (a+t)^2$ and simplifying gives us
$$ x = \dfrac{a^2 (a+t)^2 b}{t^2} = \dfrac{a^4 b}{t^2} + \dfrac{2 a^3 b}{t} + a^2 b$$
Any prime that divides $t$ must divide $2$, $a$ or $b$, and can't have too high a degree.

In the first example, $a=2$, $b=5$, $80/t^2 + 80/t$ is an integer; the possible primes are $2$ and $5$, and it's not hard to show that the only possibilities
are $t = 1,2,4$, corresponding to $y = 5 (2+t)^2 =  45, 80, 180$ and
$x = 180, 80, 45$ respectively.

Now try $a = 1$, $b = 2014 = 2 \times 19 \times 53$.

EDIT: By the way, $2016$ will be an interesting year.

Comment: Bravo for generalization!! Thanks.

Comment: very clever, neat and nice answer. 1000 times better than me one.

Answer (score 1):

Let$${1\over\sqrt{x}}+{1\over\sqrt{y}} = {1\over\sqrt{20}}.$$
Then $$\sqrt {5x}+\sqrt {5y}=\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{4}=t$$ for some real number $t.$ From here we can obtain that, 
$$xy=16t^2,\,\,\,\,\,\  x+y=\frac{t^2}{5}-8t$$ Since $x,y$ are integers note that $t$ is also an integer. $$z^2-(\frac{t^2}{5}-8t)z+16t^2=0$$ has the roots $x$ and $y.$
$$5z^2+(40t-t^2)z+80t^2=0$$ If we consider the discriminant of this quadratic equation, there should exist a n integer $d$ such that $$d^2=(t^2-40t)^2-1600t^2=t^3(t-80).$$ Con you continue from here? Similar idea works for your (b)  also.